# How to use Order by in function with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-order-by

I use `order by` without function order by work success by use below code

```
SELECT 
    Invoice.Text, Invoice.Value 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         T_Invoice.id,  System_Date As Sys_Date, 
         CONCAT(DATEPART(MM, T_Invoice.System_Date), '/', DATEPART(YY, T_Invoice.System_Date)) AS Text, 
         CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(T_Invoice.System_Date as DATE)) AS Value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(DATEPART(MM, T_Invoice.System_Date), '/', DATEPART(YY, T_Invoice.System_Date)) ORDER BY T_Invoice.System_Date DESC) AS RowNumber 
     FROM 
         T_Invoice) As Invoice 
INNER JOIN
    T_Invoice_Items ON Invoice.id = T_Invoice_Items.Invoice
WHERE 
    T_Invoice_Items.Charge_type = 3 AND Invoice.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY 
    Invoice.Sys_Date
```

But when work with function order by not work and error

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Use below code

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_Invoice_Date]
    (@Charge BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN 
        (SELECT 
             Invoice.Text, Invoice.Value 
         FROM            
             (SELECT 
                  T_Invoice.id,  System_Date As Sys_Date, 
                  CONCAT(DATEPART(MM, T_Invoice.System_Date), '/', DATEPART(YY, T_Invoice.System_Date)) AS Text, 
                  CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CAST(T_Invoice.System_Date as DATE)) AS Value,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(DATEPART(MM, T_Invoice.System_Date), '/', DATEPART(YY, T_Invoice.System_Date)) ORDER BY T_Invoice.System_Date DESC) AS RowNumber 
              FROM 
                  T_Invoice) As Invoice 
         INNER JOIN
             T_Invoice_Items ON Invoice.id = T_Invoice_Items.Invoice
         WHERE 
             T_Invoice_Items.Charge_type = @Charge 
             AND Invoice.RowNumber = 1
         ORDER BY
             Invoice.Sys_Date)
```

Comment: Add Top to SELECT clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `SELECT` to this:

```
SELECT  top (100) percent
```

Edited:

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> The ORDER BY clause is not valid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, and subqueries, unless either the TOP or OFFSET and FETCH
>   clauses are also specified. When ORDER BY is used in these objects,
>   the clause is used only to determine the rows returned by the TOP
>   clause or OFFSET and FETCH clauses. The ORDER BY clause does not
>   guarantee ordered results when these constructs are queried, unless
>   ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.

Edited2:

Please, pay attention on this:

> The ORDER BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when these
>   constructs are queried, unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query
>   itself.

The best way to do ordering is:

```
select * from your_table_func() order by your_column;
```

**Not in function**.

Answer (score 1):

Inline table valued functions are table expressions. Table expressions cannot have an `order by` because they are supposed to return a `set` and there is no meaning of ordering of elements in a `set`.
You should instead add the `Sys_Date` field in your function result and use order by when calling the function.

```
SELECT text, 
       value 
FROM   [dbo].[fn_invoice_date](..)
ORDER  BY sys_date
```